# No such module named "official" when I try to use tf-models-official

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, jupyter-lab, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I am going through a lab walkthrough done by Google Cloud about [Transformer and BERT Models](https://youtu.be/6hhvQb8tSPs?t=84) and I am working in a JupyterLab notebook and using TensorFlow 2.10.

One of the modules I am trying to call is `from official.nlp import optimization` (**I linked the video at exactly the time where they go over import statements**).

My problem is that I keep getting an error which says that there is no such module as "official", even when I have successfully installed it on my command prompt.

I already tried to do `!pip install -U tf-models-official==2.10` but the error still remains.

I have no idea what to do. I was facing the same issues with another import statement, `import tensorflow_text as text`, but I fixed it by doing `!pip install -U tensorflow_text==2.10`. I took inspiration from this to try to fix my error on "official", but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Shayaan Uddin, I tried replicating the code and found the same error. But error got resolved when I dont specify any version while installing tf-models-officials, which will also install supporting tensorflow-text as dependency with latest version and use this code as well `import from tensorflow_models import nlp`. Please check this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/75776bc9521a6f77449bba90c71160eb/76527755.ipynb) for the reference.